# Changing variables during run-time without the use of hooks in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, hook

I want to be able to do the following (if it's possible) in C/C++.

I have a file such as this:

> *Initialvariables.txt*
>   a = 5
>   b = 2
>   c = 8

And code which looks like this:

`int main(int argc char *argv[])

{

 int a;

int b;

int c;


LoadInitialVariables("Initialvariables.txt");

}`

Where a,b,c are variables and the file "Initialvariables.txt" contains the initial values which can change after compilation.
**Is it possible to create LoadInitialVariables such that if a new person came along to change the code, they could simply add in a new int and add a new line to "initialvariables.txt" and the code will do the rest to set up the initial variable?**
The aim is not to have hard-coded hooks but to make LoadInitialVariables as generic as possible.
The difficulty to me seems to come from the fact that the compiler strips the symbols and thus the executable will not know what a, b, c, etc. is without the appropriate hook. I would rather not have to specify the hooks (unless it simply decorates the int) if it's possible.

Comment: If you can make your file just numbers, it's easy to just read them in and store them into a vector and return that. Without just numbers, the same principle applies, but you have to get around the other text in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have `LoadInitialVariables()` load the text file into a `std::map<std::string, int>`, then you could refer to the `int` values by name whenever needed, eg:

```
void LoadInitialVariables(const std::string &fileName, std::map<std::string, int> &variables)
{
    variables.clear();

    char name[256];
    int value;

    for (each line in the file)
    {
        std::string line = ...;
        if (sscanf(line.c_str(), "%s = %d", name, &value) == 2)
            variables[name] = value;
    }
    ...
}

int main(int argc char *argv[])
{
    std::map<std::string, int> variables;
    LoadInitialVariables("Initialvariables.txt", variables);

    int a = variables["a"];
    int b = variables["b"];
    int c = variables["c"];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

why not use a `std::map<string, int>`?

what you're proposing doesn't make a lot of sense without using a vector or map and iterating over it later. if a user just added a variable in main and added code to parse and assign it in your load function... the existing code wouldn't have any way of knowing about it without further changes.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to create LoadInitialVariables such that if a new person came along to change the code, they could simply add in a new int and add a new line to "initialvariables.txt" and the code will do the rest to set up the initial variable?

No.

But it is not terribly hard to build a support layer with which programmers register variables that can then be set by a file-parser. The simplest means is the c++ `std::map<std::string, int>` that [VBRonPaulFan suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290664/2509). In c you have to write a bit more code, but it can still be done in a few dozen line (if you only need to support one type: a few hundred to support a reasonable but fixed set of types).

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29)? It's not available in C++, at least not out of the box. You could always do some kind of horrible C-style macro...

```
#define READ_FROM_FILE(X) X = some_function_that_greps_file_for(#X)

int a, b, c;
READ_FROM_FILE(a);
READ_FROM_FILE(b);
READ_FROM_FILE(c);
```

But it's much easier, safer, and maintainable to use the `map<string, int>`.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple library you might find useful. It allows you to mark all the required variables using `tunable(var_name)` and they will be modifiable whenever you enter the interactive console with `tunablecmd()`.

https://github.com/miloszmaki/tunable-cpp